# SharePoint 2013 Add Read more link in Announcement web part each list items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I want to add Read more link in my Announcement Web Part
I followed this blog post: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/07/styling-announcements-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/

I created an external javascript file and put the blow Javascript code:

```
(function () {
var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};
    itemCtx.Templates.Header ="<div><b>Announcements</b></div><table>";
    itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
    itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";
itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {
var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;
var _announcementID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
return "<tr><td><p><b>"+_announcementTitle+"</b></p>"+_announcementDesc+"<a     href='/sites/testdev/Lists/Announce/DispForm.aspx?ID='+_announcementID +'>Read More...</a>   </td></tr>";
}
```

when I put the link inside JS Link it doesn't work

i have also tried another blogs post with the blow codes which I have putted in my ItemStyle.xsl but it also does not works.

```
 <xsl:template name="removeMarkup">
   <xsl:param name="string" />
   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains($string, '&lt;')">
          <xsl:variable name="nextString">
                 <xsl:call-template name="removeMarkup">
                 <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&gt;')" />
                 </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($string, '&lt;'), $nextString)" />
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
   </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template name="ReadMoreAnnouncements" match="Row[@Style='ReadMoreAnnouncements']" mode="itemstyle">
<br />
<div class="RMAnnouncementsTitle">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
</div>
<div class="RMAnnouncementsBody">
    <xsl:variable name="body">
        <xsl:call-template name="removeMarkup">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@Body"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($body,1,190)" />
    ...
    <br />
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            /Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID">
            </xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            RMAnnouncementsMoreLink
        </xsl:attribute>
        read more
    </a>
 </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am not a Javascript Expert but shouldn't there be the numeral value of character limit somewhere in the JS? :-)

Comment: When you say something doesn't work, please describe the behaviour that seems incorrect: error message, upset expectation, etc.

Comment: You can debug Javascript with IE, Chrome and Firefox. Open up the developer console (usually F12), search the javascript, set a breakpoint and refresh the page.

Comment: After adding xsl in ItemStyle, you have to add content query webpart and set presentation style to ReadMoreAnnouncement. Then only it show the custom style in your announcement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template file from the article that you mentioned in the question contains some typos and *hard-coded* parameters like `title` and `list url`.

Instead I would recommend you to utilize the template provided below.

Regarding template file, in fact, there are several ways how to apply custom template to List View, and not necessary only via `JSLink` property. Below is demonstrated probably *the easiest way* of customizing Announcements.

### How to apply changes

1) Open the page where `Announcements` web part resides in Edit Mode

2) Add `Script Editor` web part on the page. Then click `Edit Snippet` in `Script Editor` web part and embed the following code:

```
<script>

(function () {

    var viewCtx = {};
    viewCtx.Templates = {};

    viewCtx.Templates.Header = "<table>";
    viewCtx.Templates.Item = AnnouncementItem;
    viewCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";

    viewCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
    viewCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(viewCtx);

})();

function AnnouncementItem(ctx) {
    return String.format("<tr><td><p><b>{3}</b></p>{1}<a href='{2}/DispForm.aspx?ID={0}'> Read More…</a></td></tr>",
    ctx.CurrentItem.ID,ctx.CurrentItem.Body,ctx.listUrlDir,ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
}

</script>
```

3)Save the page.

That's it.

**Result**

[image]

**Update**

```
function AnnouncementItem(ctx) {
    var headlineLimit = 300;
    var headline = $(ctx.CurrentItem.Body).text(); 
    if (headline.length > headlineLimit)
    {
        headline = headline.substring(0,headlineLimit);
    }
    return String.format("<tr><td><p><b>{3}</b></p>{1}<a href='{2}/DispForm.aspx?ID={0}'> Read More…</a></td></tr>",
    ctx.CurrentItem.ID,headline,ctx.listUrlDir,ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much appreciated. please if you help me on limiting of characters if they become more than 300 characters it should put... again thanks allot for your great code and help

Comment: Glad it helped you. Regarding limiting of characters, see the Update section of the answer, it demonstrates how to truncate the body column. You just need to replace AnnouncementItem function.

Comment: Great code thank you very much it worked prefect, thanks for your help.

Comment: Very nice and best code

Answer (score 3):

You have to make some correction in your javascript mentioned in first editor. As it work fine in my case.

1. Copy JavaScript in notepad and make below changes
2. Replace double quotes “ and ” with normal quotes ".
3. Replace single quotes ’ with normal single quote '.
4. Check your list url properly ’/Lists/Announcements / DispForm.aspx?ID = ’ + _announcementID + ’. As remove spaces between them and make it as '/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID ='+announcementID
5. While uploading JavaScript file in MasterPageGallery as a JavaScript Display template. Assign list id 104 instead of 107.
6. While giving url in JSLink property in your webpart, copy url first in notepad and replace quotes with normal quotes then apply it.

Be very careful when giving url in JSlink property. In most of cases it doesn't work because of incorrect url. Your url must start with **~site/_catalogs** then your javascript file name. Dont' put javascript file in any folder in masterpage gallery. Directly put in masterpage gallery then see the changes.

Your JS file seems ok, put the url in your webpart JSLink property **~site/_catalogs/masterpage/testa.js**

It will work like a charm!

Comment: My dear friend I don't know why it is not working I followed your steps but still I can't see any read more link to be added at the end of my each Announcement list item.

Comment: Do I need to modify the Javascript more. I have created a folder by the name of JS in my _catalog folder and created a javascript file and putted this script there and copied the link and putted in JSlink, don't know why it is not working

Comment: @MehdiJalal, I think you need to navigate into your master page gallery and from there you can upload a Javascript Display Template as ateet said in his answer. Could you try it like that? :-)

Comment: I have uploaded my Javascript as a Javascript display template but it is not working

Comment: @MehdiJalal Could you edit your original question and paste your current JavaScript here in the code view? :-)

Comment: @MehdiJalal Don't upload javascript file in folder in _catalog folder. Just simply upload it directly in MasterPage gallery as a Javascript Display template. And be care about providing links. Give like ~sites/_catalog/filename.js

Comment: See my edited post now!

Comment: Dear friend @ateet I did uploaded in master page folder and rechecked it but it is not working. if you have a better solution please help me

Comment: Could you confirm  me that you replace double quotes with normal quotes?
Can you paste the url that you are providing to JSlink. And JS file property screenshot that you uploaded in MAsterpagegallery?

Comment: I have updated my script you can see also my js file is inside the masterpage folder the link is: https://MyServer.com/sites/testdev/_catalogs/masterpage/testa.js

Comment: JS file seems ok, put this link in your JSLink property ~site/_catalogs/masterpage/testa.js