# SharePoint 2013 add Read More link in a webpart Announcements using JavaScript

Tags: development, javascript, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013, office-365-developer

I have created a slider using `bxSlider` and it works perfectly, but in case to show all text that comes from `Announcements List`, I want to display only 100 characters and show `read more` link which it should redirect you to current item in Announcement list. Here is my slider: I.E

[image: bx slider]

And here is my Announcements list:
[image]

I also tried to make this working [Read more link in webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115402/sharepoint-2013-add-read-more-link-in-announcement-web-part-each-list-items) but I could not achieve my goal.

I was wondering if someone could help me.

Comment: This is not really a SharePoint related question.

Comment: unfurtunately, it is; ...

Comment: Show your bxSlider code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Atish solved my problem and his code was like this:

```
     <div>
     <a class="moveIt" href="/sites/contoso/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>">Read more</a>
     </div>
```

And it is working perfectly

thanks @Atish

Comment: so this worked dynamically?  did you put in a JSLink?  can you provide more info...