# Announcement Slider (No Picture)

Tags: announcements

Has anyone come around a rotator/slider that rotates text only?  We have had trouble in the past with picture ones as we would always have to make sure that the pictures were specific sizes so my manager said that he only wants text to be in the slider.  We are thinking of just the article heading and an excerpt.  has anyone come across anything like that?

I have been searching he internet and I have mostly come across image sliders, most of which is for SharePoint 2010 when I am using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a text only carousel. You can read your announcement items using REST and display them using bootstrap. All this will be written in a javascript file and will be placed on a page using a Content Editor Webpart. I can give you an excerpt if you think you can go this route. Let me know. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used bxSlider to have my announcements scroll like a news ticker.  I'm sure you could utilize it to function as a normal carousel or even a slider.  The code I used is in another question I asked here... [Body does not display when truncating in Announcements Webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205421/body-does-not-display-when-truncating-in-announcements-webpart)

Comment: I am going to try that.  I am new to this and I am having difficulty understanding where to put things when I read threads.  I was hoping to find something that I can follow from start to end instead of code snippets.

Comment: Ah. Okay, so if you use bxSlider (or another jquery slider plugin), you will need to download the latest version (http://bxslider.com/). Then either upload the directory to a Style Library (document library) or in the Master Page Gallery.  Then create your Announcements List & add it as a webpart to the page. (Make sure all fields are visible in view).  then add a script editor & copy the code I referenced there & make sure to paste the bxslider jquery ref & script in the script editor as well.