# Announcement customization - Follow up to pre existing solution

Tags: web-part

I am using an solution from  [Learning Sharepoint](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/07/styling-announcements-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/) this is not working. Found some help here [disqus.com](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/learningsharepoint/styling_announcements_with_javascript_using_js_link_in_sharepoint_2013/) since the first link got some errors to the code.

```
   (function () {

var itemCtx = {};
 itemCtx.Templates = {};

itemCtx.Templates.Header = “<div><b>Announcements</b></div><table>”;
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
 itemCtx.Templates.Footer = “</table>”;

itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
 itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;

var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;

var _announcementID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;

return “<tr><td><p><b>” + _announcementTitle + “</b></p>” + 

_announcementDesc +”<a href=’/Lists/Company%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=’+ _announcementID +’> Read More…</a></td></tr>”;
     }
```

Best help is from this page and the post here [add-read-more-link-in-announcement](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115402/sharepoint-2013-add-read-more-link-in-announcement-web-part-each-list-items)

The one thing missing is the from the 1st link. Add Description text below Title and before Read me...

**What i am seeking help** for is 1, Description 2, Make the Title clickable.